# load ajax page with transparent background

Tags: jquery, opacity

I have a webapp where I load all subpages with ajax and Im trying to set the background to opacity 0 or transparent but it only gets white.

The page that I load looks like this:

```
<div id="pageid">

  <div id="header">
  header
  </div>

Text

</div>
```

And the code for trying to set the opacity:

```
$("#pageid").css({ opacity:0.1 });
```

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Update:
It was a problem with the z-index order and a display none that I had missed, thanks.

Comment: If there are only white things under the div you will see the white things !? Or is there something special under it?

Comment: Can you post your ajax code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("body").css({ opacity:0.1 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it is not showing the underlaying div. Maybe it has something to do with the z-index order, have to check.
I cant find anything setting the white color in the css.

Comment: we already changed the `body` opacity and `z-index` wont work. Can you post your `ajax` call code with your question?

Answer (score 0):

The background of a normal div is transparent already, there's nothing you need to do. Probably you have some other error or a misconception about how things should work.